# pushing content of textarea into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea and i want to push its content into an array that I defined

I have created a Tasks component and used the onClick property to push the value of its textarea's innerhtml into the array.

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import Tasks from './tasks.js';
import './App.css';

let tasks= [
  {name:""},
  {name:""},
  {name:""},
  {name:""},
  {name:""}

]

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tasks onClick={()=>{

        tasks.push(this.props.value)
      }} />
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

tasks.js:

```
import React from 'react'



class Tasks extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>
<textarea value={this.props.value} ></textarea>
<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Add task</button>
        </div>)

    }

}



export default Tasks
```

The app compiled successfully, but when I click on the button, the "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" error appears

Comment: textarea has not value and you must put value between tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain state in child component to store value of text-area,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    }
  }
```

You can set state value, when your text-area change,

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
}
```

On the click of the button, you need to pass the value from text-area to parent component like,

```
<textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<button onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.value)}>
     Add task
</button>
```

In parent component, you can push value of text-area into your array.

```
function addData(val) {
  tasks.push(val)
  console.log(tasks)
}
<Tasks onClick={value => addData(value)} />
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-d4lix?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you, this works! But I didn't quite understand the handleChange part :)

Comment: As user start typing in text-area handleChange function start working and sets text-area value(typed by user) in state.

Comment: Later on, I tried to return the new array using       <ul>{tasks.map((e)=><Item item={e} />)}
</ul> 
in the App.js, with Item being class Item extends React.Component{ 
 render(){ return(
        <li>{this.props.item}
        </li>
    );
}}
But nothing is being returned!! however in the console.log, the array is there perfectly

Comment: As your tasks array is array of object you need to do this, `<li>{this.props.item.name}</li>`.